# Forgerock Directory Service Control Panel.bat file missing

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch-file

I'm Install a new Directory Service on my PC,but the control panel.bat file can't generate, that one file is missing,I'm was able to continue the installation process.

Directory Service Version:-6.5.0-Eval

OS Type:- Windows 7 Enterprises(Service Pack1)

Link:- https://backstage.forgerock.com/downloads/browse/ds/latest

Link:-https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/ds/6.5/install-guide/

Path:-C:\programfile\forgerock\ds-eval-6.5.0\opendj\bat

How to solve the issue Guide me.

[DS Folder Path Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cj1ZU.png)

Comment: Why are you not asking ForgeRock?  I will also point out that this product was free not long ago and went under the name "OpenAM".  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenAM .  You can find free forks of it here:  http://www.openidentityplatform.org/

Comment: ForgeRock Directory Services is built on what was the OpenDJ open source project (not OpenAM).

Answer (score 0):

The ControlPanel was deprecated and removed from ForgeRock Directory Services 6.0.
If you need a graphical LDAP browser, we recommend to use Apache Directory Studio.